# Subset of spatial data causes slow SQL Spatial STIntersects

Tags: python, sql, intersection, performance

I've been having an issue were a specific subset of data causes an SQL spatial intersect to run *extremely* slowly. I am running sets of 1000 points against a subset of polygon layer to be intersected.

I know that the intersect works, and when running on a subset of 125,000 - 500,000 records, it takes practically no time at all. However, when I use the smallest subset (~25k records) that the polygon layer contains, the intersect takes over a full minute.

It is worth noting that the records are mutually exclusive (they're selected off of a name field in the where clause), so the records selected in the 25,000 point subset would not be present in the 125,000 or 500,000 point subset. That makes me think there must be something wrong with those points being selected when the intersect runs slowly, but for the life of me I can't figure out what that might be.

I'm running the spatial intersect from a Python script (to be published as a geoprocessing service) but the intersect behaves identically in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: which Database are you using, and what does explain say about the queries?

Comment: I would start looking into geometry checking and repair.  Here is a little info on SQL Server, but because we don't know what database you are using, it will be helpful for all of us if you edit with as much information as possible.  http://boomphisto.blogspot.com/2011/06/sql-server-invalid-geometry.html

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain the exact SQL ***and*** the [query execution plan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan) for each